# m functions of n variables in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, nonlinear-functions

Suppose I want to construct the following function:

```
f <- function(beta) c(y[1]*beta[1]+z[1]*1/beta[2],
                      y[2]*beta[1]+z[2]*1/beta[2],
                      :   :     :    :
                    y[i]*beta[1]^2+z[i]*1/beta[2])
```

Suppose I have the following data.

```
y = 1:10
z = 10:19
f <- function(beta) cbind(y) %*% beta^2   
jacobian(f, c(1)) #where c(1) is the value for beta.
g <- function(beta) cbind(z) %*% 1/beta
jacobian(g, c(1)) #where c(1) is the value for beta.
```

Which yields the desired outputs for f and g respectively:

```
     [,1]
 [1,]    2
 [2,]    4
 [3,]    6
 [4,]    8
 [5,]   10
 [6,]   12
 [7,]   14
 [8,]   16
 [9,]   18
[10,]   20

#and

     [,1]
 [1,]  -10
 [2,]  -11
 [3,]  -12
 [4,]  -13
 [5,]  -14
 [6,]  -15
 [7,]  -16
 [8,]  -17
 [9,]  -18
[10,]  -19
```

Now I could just merge these two matrices to obtain the jacobian of f and g. However, I would like just one function for the desired output.

I have tried the following but this does not yield the outcome I would like:

```
u <- function(beta) (cbind(y, z) %*% cbind(beta^2,1/beta))
jacobian(u, c(1,1))
```

Gives the incorrect output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    2   20
 [2,]    4   22
 [3,]    6   24
 [4,]    8   26
 [5,]   10   28
 [6,]   12   30
 [7,]   14   32
 [8,]   16   34
 [9,]   18   36
[10,]   20   38
[11,]   -1  -10
[12,]   -2  -11
[13,]   -3  -12
[14,]   -4  -13
[15,]   -5  -14
[16,]   -6  -15
[17,]   -7  -16
[18,]   -8  -17
[19,]   -9  -18
[20,]  -10  -19
```

Does anyone know how I can combine function f and g such that I get a 10 x 2 Jacobian matrix?

The jacobian function is structured as follow

```
library('pracma')
jacobian(f, x0, heps = .Machine$double.eps^(1/3), ...)
f: m functions of n variables.
x0: Numeric vector of length n.
heps: This is h in the derivative formula.
jacobian(): Computes the derivative of each function f_j by variable x_i separately, taking the discrete step h.
```

The desired output I would like to obtain is

```
     [,1]   [,2]
 [1,]    2   -10
 [2,]    4   -11
 [3,]    6   -12
 [4,]    8   -13
 [5,]   10   -14
 [6,]   12   -15
 [7,]   14   -16
 [8,]   16   -17
 [9,]   18   -18
[10,]   20   -19
```

Comment: Could you kindly give an example of the output you _do_ desire?  I suppose it could be inferred from your definition of `f` at the very top, but you seem to have made a typo or two: the exponent `^2` is missing from `beta[1]^2` for `i` ∈ {`1`, `2`}.

Comment: Also, could you please disambiguate your `jacobian()` function? A quick search reveals functions like `numDeriv::jacobian()` and `pracma::jacobian()`; and I imagine there are further packages with a `jacobian()` function. Which is yours?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. I have edited the initial post to give answers to your questions

Comment: Awesome!  I have your answer; just typing it up.

Comment: That's amazing! take your time.

Comment: Just finished! You only made one mistake, which is easy to fix, but I took advantage of the opportunity to code a generalized function, which can accommodate an arbitrary number of columns (`y`, `z`, ...) with a `beta` of arbitrary size and a list of arbitrary functions (`x^2`, `1/x`, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Note

You went wrong in one particular place:

> ```
> u <- function(beta) (cbind(y, z) %*% cbind(beta^2,1/beta))
> #                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> #                                            HERE
> ```

You used `cbind(beta^2, 1/beta)` to create a 2 × 2 matrix

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
```

rather than using `c(beta[1]^2, 1/beta[2]))` to create a vector `c(1^2, 1/1)` of length 2.

When you performed your matrix multiplication `cbind(y, z) %*% ...`, you consequently multiplied your **10** × 2 matrix `cbind(y, z)` by a 2 × **2** matrix, which yielded a **10** × **2** matrix as the output for your function `u()`. With a properly generated vector, however, the product would have been a 10 × 1 matrix.

Unsurprisingly, `numDeriv::jacobian()` gave a different result for a 10 × **2** matrix than for your intended 10 × **1** matrix.

## Generalized Solution

I can give you a generalized function `h()`, which can be wrapped by `u()` to create the "pseudofunction" you describe here:

> ```
> function(beta) c(y[1] * beta[1]^2 + z[1] * 1/beta[2],
>                  y[2] * beta[1]^2 + z[2] * 1/beta[2],
>                    :   :     :    :
>                  y[i] * beta[1]^2 + z[i] * 1/beta[2])
> ```

For `h()`, we supply the arguments

- `beta`: a numeric vector, of length *n*.
- `funs`: a `list` of *n* `function`s.
- `...`: *n* numeric vectors each of length *m*, which will be consolidated as columns in a single *m* × *n* matrix **A**. Alternatively, the numeric `matrix` **A** itself.
- `expand`: a logical value indicating how `funs` should be applied to `beta`, to yield the structure by which the *m* × *n* matrix **A** will be multiplied:

  - `TRUE`: Apply to `beta` (as a whole) each of the *n* listed `funs`, and then consolidate each of the *n* results as a column of length *n* in an *n* × *n* matrix **B**.
  - `FALSE`: Apply the the *i*th `function` in `funs` to the *i*th element in `beta`, and consolidate each of the *n* results as an element in a vector **b** of length *n*.

and we receive either the *m* × *n* matrix **AB** (`expand = TRUE`) or the vector **Ab** of length *m* (`expand = FALSE`). Your purposes require the latter as input to `pracma::jacobian()`.

Here is the definition of `h()`

```
h <- function(beta, funs, ..., expand = FALSE) {
  # If there is only one function, encapsulate it in a list for mapply.
  if(!is.list(funs)) {
    funs <- list(funs)
  }
  
  # If expansion is desired, encapsulate beta in a list for mapply, to yield
  # a set of vectors that can be consolidated as columns into a matrix.
  # Otherwise, do neither, to yield a set of numbers consolidated as elements
  # in a vector.
  if(isTRUE(expand)) {
    beta <- list(beta)
    consolidate <- cbind
  } else {
    beta <- as.vector(beta)
    consolidate <- base::c
  }
  
  return(
    as.matrix(cbind(...) %*%
              do.call(consolidate,
                      mapply(FUN = function(f, x) {
                                     as.vector(sapply(X = x, FUN = f, simplify = TRUE))
                                   },
                             funs, beta,
                             SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))
  )
}
```

and here is the convenience function `u()` to wrap `h()` for your specific purposes:

```
y <- 1:10
z <- 10:19

u <- function(beta) {
  h(beta = beta, funs = list(function(x){x^2}, function(x){1/x}), y, z, expand = FALSE)
}
```

You can now use

```
pracma::jacobian(u, c(1,1))
```

to obtain your desired output:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    2  -10
 [2,]    4  -11
 [3,]    6  -12
 [4,]    8  -13
 [5,]   10  -14
 [6,]   12  -15
 [7,]   14  -16
 [8,]   16  -17
 [9,]   18  -18
[10,]   20  -19
```

Comment: Thank you for this extensive workout! It works perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you wanted to simply apply the correction in my **Note** and proceed with your original code, that would work too. I just wanted `h()` to provide more flexibility for future situations. Specifically, you won't have to type out `c(beta[1]^2, 1/beta[2], ...))` by hand, which would be unpleasant for lengthy `beta`s and for functions (of the form `function(x){...}`) more complex than `x^2`. Neither will you have to type out `cbind(y, z, ...)` by hand, which would be unpleasant for many vectors. I hope this comes in handy! :)

Comment: I love the flexibility of your proposed model. However, suppose now instead of just one parameter function beta[1]^2. I have a two-parameter function: beta[1]^2+ beta[2] as one function. How do I incorporate this as a function of just x for example? I tried something like function(x){x[1]^2+x[2]} but I am not sure whether this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Hmmm...let me think.

Comment: Just updated it with a new function `h2()`. Let me know if this is what you had in mind. Currently for `h2()`, the *i*th `function` in `funs` will operate on the *entire* vector `beta`, and the scalar result will be stored as the *i*th element in the vector **b** of length *n*. The output of `h2()` will be the vector **Ab** of length *m*, where **A** was the original *m* × *n* matrix supplied in `...`.

Comment: It is not precisely what I suggest. I think the problem lies in the definition of a Jacobian. Suppose you have a function of one variable then the jacobian is just one column since there is only one variable with respect to which you can take derivate. When the function becomes of two variables. For example x[1] and x[2]. The jacobian of for example y * x[1]^2 +1/ x[2] should be a matrix of two columns. Where the first column is the partial derivative with respect to x[1] multiplied by y. And the second column the partial derivative with respect to x[2] times y.

Comment: This might help: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi-matrix

Comment: I might have to get back to you on that. In the meantime, I'll remove the update, since it's not what you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your time! If you need any additional information please let me know.